# Importing a generated makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that imports another Makefile that is generated by a target in the containing one. Something like the following:

```
more_makefile:
    touch $@

include more_makefile
```

This process works fine, but you get a warning `No such file or directory` every time you hit the include line when more_makefile doesn't exist, which can confuse newcomers. Is there a way to mask this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hyphen:

```
-include more_makefile
```

Comment: I had assumed that - prevented Make from looking for rules capable of making the missing included file, but it turns out not. Thanks!

Comment: The leading hyphen will prevent make from failing if that file, in fact, doesn't exist or fails to get built correctly.

A macro that tests MAKE_RESTARTS could be written to only use -include the first time if you wanted to (that seemed to work well enough for me the time I thought I needed it).